# what m_list.SetItemState(idx, 1, FALSE) means? MFC CListCtrl

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I saw this peace of code `m_list.SetItemState(idx, 1, FALSE)` from MFC based project.

my question is what **1** and **FALSE** mean?

I saw that state `LVIS_FOCUSED` is `0x0001`, so I think **1** is `LVIS_FOCUSED`, but why they didn't use just `LVIS_FOCUSED` ?

And detailed explanation about 3rd parameter (for example when it is FALSE) is not given ([`CListCtrl::SetItemState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=msvc-170#setitemstate) )

Comment: Using `FALSE` (which is equal to zero) as the third argument will be "mask" specifying that no state bits should be changed. So that call would appear to be pointless. Are you *sure* that the `m_list` is actually a `CListCtrl`?

Comment: So, those code is actually doing nothing, right? and Yes, ```m_list``` is ```ClistCtrl```.

Comment: From my understanding of the documentation you linked and how such masks work: Yes, it's doing nothing.

Comment: The `nMask` parameter should contain at least one state bit, ie the bit you want to change (set or clear, specified in the `nState` parameter). Using `FALSE` which is actually `int` will make the mask 0, ie has no effect. The author could have used `0` instead (still no effect though), the mask is not of boolean type, neither has a "boolean" meaning (like the Win32 `BOOL` type), it is a "bit-mask" and the `UINT` type is the obvious choice there, using `FALSE` just confuses the reader.